# Concatenating char arrays in C++ (tricky)

Tags: c++, arrays, char

So I've got an exercise in which I have to concatenate 2 char arrays as follows:

```
const int MAXI=100;
char group[MAXI+7]="things/"
char input[MAXI];

cin >> input;
//Doing something here!
cout << group << endl;
```

Have to make smthing happen so  it returns -- things/input_text --

The tricky part is that I am not allowed to use pointers, string library or any kind of dynamic arrays.

What to do?

EDIT: I dont need to print it, I need the variable to has the value: things/input_text, as I'm going to use for something else!

EDIT2: I can't use the < string > library, which means, I can't use strcat() or anything on that library. I'm provided another module which is triggered as follows:

```
void thing(group, stuff, more_stuff);
```

That's it.

Comment: print one then the other?

Comment: You want it in C or in C++? C has `strcat` & `strncpy` etc... to be used with extreme care. C++ gives you `std::string`

Comment: returns or prints?  there's a big difference

Comment: @luser droog can't, becouse i need the variable to be used in an external thing, it doesn't require to be used as a print, but to use the variable as a tool for something else in the program.

Comment: Write one function that represents the string. char str(int x) { if (x<7) return group[x]; else return input[x-7]; }

Comment: @basile Cant add the <string> library so I can't use strcat.

Comment: "The tricky part" isn't well described or motivated. ... Why? And precisely *what* can you not use? And why?

Comment: Uhm... I would *hope* that this is for homework and not for actual production code.

Comment: @NikBougalis obviously! I'm just learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int MAXI=100;

int main()
{
    char group[MAXI+7]="things/";
    char input[MAXI];
    cin >> input;
    for(int i=0; i<MAXI; i++)
    {
        group[7+i]=input[i];
        if(input[i]=='\0') break;//if the string is shorter than MAXI
    }
    cout << group << endl;
}
```

Comment: ok, yeah, I'm totally useless, this is like so easy yet I was bound to find a hidden way to do it. Thank you soooo much :)

Comment: Your code, as is, may leave `group` without a NULL terminator, and that would be *bad*. You should also highlight the danger of a buffer overflow in the `cin >> input` statement using a very bright marker to help the OP learn how to spot potential issues early.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const int MAXI=100;
    char group[MAXI+7]="things/";
    char input[MAXI];

    // Warning: this could potentially overflow the buffer
    // if the user types a string longer than MAXI - 1
    // characters
    cin >> input;

    // Be careful - group only contains MAXI plus 7 characters
    // and 7 of those are already taken. Which means we can only
    // write up to MAXI-1 characters, including the NULL terminator.
    for(int i = 0; (i < MAXI - 1) && (input[i] != 0); i++)
    {
        group[i + 7] = input[i];
        group[i + 8] = 0; // ensure null termination, always
    }

    cout << group << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can avoid the repeated `group[i+8] = 0` if you are so inclined, by taking the `i` out of loop scope. That's left as an exercise to the OP.

Comment: I luv you both <(^.^)>